# 5D Scatter Plot is too big, how to modify the size attribute?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have followed this tutorial:
https://towardsdev.com/multi-dimension-visualization-in-python-part-i-85c13e9b7495

https://towardsdev.com/multi-dimension-visualization-in-python-part-ii-8c56d861923a

I see that the 5D scatter plot is too big, how to modify the size, makes it 1/10 or 1/50 of its current size?

The csv is like this:
[image: 1]

The plot with oversize scattered circles:
[image: 1]

the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

dataidxbluechip = pd.read_csv("/home/browni/LasthrimProjection/Python/csv/idxbluechipstocks.csv", index_col=0, parse_dates = True)
dataidxpenny = pd.read_csv("/home/browni/LasthrimProjection/Python/csv/idxpennystocks.csv", index_col=0, parse_dates = True)

# Print first 5 rows of data
print(dataidxbluechip.head())
print(dataidxpenny.head())

# Store stocks type as an attribute
dataidxbluechip['stocks_type'] = 'IDX Blue chip'
dataidxpenny['stocks_type'] = 'IDX Penny Stocks'

# bucket stocks quality scores into qualitative quality labels
dataidxbluechip['PER 2023'] = dataidxbluechip['per2023'].apply(lambda value: 'low'
        if value <= 10 
        else 'medium' if value <= 15
        else 'high')
dataidxbluechip['PER 2023'] = pd.Categorical(dataidxbluechip['PER 2023'],
            categories=['low','medium','high'])

dataidxpenny['PER 2023'] = dataidxpenny['per2023'].apply(lambda value: 'low'
        if value <= 10 
        else 'medium' if value <= 15
        else 'high')
dataidxpenny['PER 2023'] = pd.Categorical(dataidxpenny['PER 2023'],
            categories=['low','medium','high'])

allstocks = pd.concat([dataidxbluechip, dataidxpenny])

# Print first 5 rows of data after being concatenate and replace
# the column of per2023 with PER 2023 stating the level of PER
print(allstocks.head())

# Visualizing 5-D mix data using bubble charts
# leveraging the concepts of hue, size and depth

g = sns.FacetGrid(allstocks, col="stocks_type", hue='PER 2023',
                  col_order=['IDX Blue chip', 'IDX Penny Stocks'], 
          hue_order=['low', 'medium', 'high'],
                  aspect=1.2, palette=sns.light_palette('navy', 4)[1:])

# The size='bvps2023' seems problematic.. ask..
g.map_dataframe(sns.scatterplot, "pricejan2010", "debtequityratio2023", alpha=0.9, 
      edgecolor='white', linewidth=0.5, size='bvps2023', 
      sizes=(allstocks['bvps2023'].min(), allstocks['bvps2023'].max()))

fig = g.fig 
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.8, wspace=0.3)
fig.suptitle('Stocks Type - Book Value - Debt Equity Ratio - PER 2023', fontsize=14)
l = g.add_legend(title='Stocks PER Quality Class')

plt.show()
fig.savefig('5dscatterplot.png')
```

Comment: `sizes` does not works, I try to replace `size=`bvps2023`` with `size=(5,200)` still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`size=` tells which column of the dataframe will be used to indicate the size of the scatter dots. For example, `size='weight'` will use the weight column to determine the dot sizes.  The smallest weight will be mapped to the smallest dot size, the largest weight to the largest dot size. By default, seaborn chooses some adequate sizes for the size ranges.  With `sizes=(min_size, max_size)` another range can be set.  Setting `mpg['weight'].min(), mpg['weight'].max()` will set the range of dot sizes to `(1613, 5140)`.  These are extremely huge.  If you don't like the defaults (`sizes=None`), you can experiment with your own ranges, e.g. `sizes=(10, 150)`.

Note that the marker size is measures in `points**2`. A point is `1/72 inch`; points are often used for font sizes, e.g. a 12 point font. So, a dot size of `100` is comparable in size to a character with font size `10`.

Here is some code to demonstrate what's happening, starting from seaborn's mgp dataset:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

mpg = sns.load_dataset('mpg')

g = sns.FacetGrid(mpg, col='origin', hue='cylinders',
                  aspect=1.2, palette='turbo')

g.map_dataframe(sns.scatterplot, 'model_year', 'mpg', alpha=0.9,
                edgecolor='white', linewidth=0.5, size='weight',
                sizes=(mpg['weight'].min(), mpg['weight'].max()))
plt.show()
```

The high values for `sizes=` create huge dots:

[image: sns.scatterplot with huge dots]

The same code, but now with `sizes=(10, 150)`:

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(mpg, col='origin', hue='cylinders',
                  aspect=1.2, palette='turbo')

g.map_dataframe(sns.scatterplot, 'model_year', 'mpg', alpha=0.9,
                edgecolor='white', linewidth=0.5, size='weight',
                sizes=(10, 150))
```

[image: sns.scatterplot with custom size dots]

Comment: I finally understood that I am not stuck with `sizes=(allstocks['bvps2023'].min(), allstocks['bvps2023'].max())` I can change it.. thanks.

Comment: Your answer can help a lot of other people. This might come in handy.